# Show and Hide img using vba

Tags: image, vba, hide, show

I have to show or hide an image on different sheets. Can anyone help me?

Here is my vba code:

```
Sub showhide()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
    .Visible = Not .Visible
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: try '.visible = False'

Answer (score 2):

Just check if is already visible or not and do the oppsite:

```
Sub showhide()
 With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1") 
  If .Visible = False Then
    .Visible = True
  Else
    .Visible = False        
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather have a foreach statement where you can loop trough your imgs and set them as you please

```
Set shapeList = ActiveSheet.Shapes
        For Each shp In shapeList
            If shp.Visible = true Then
                shp.Visible=false
           else
                shp.Visible=false
            End If
        Next shp
```

Of course you have to launch your event on each page with a button or something.
Or even when the page loads set the img to this function